# women dying during menstraution cycle

Tags: women, death, menstruation

I have heard that women and girls who die during their mentruation periods are considered to gotten bad death?

is shastras saying that death during menses cycle is bad and leads to bad birth next time?

Comment: You need a better reference than "I have heard"

Comment: I personally never heard of any such thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, women dying in her menses is considered a bad death according to the Puranas.

> Sri Krishna said, '...O Garuda, hear, I shall tell you the great secret
> about the rite of death for those who dies through serpent, tiger,
> toothed head-breaking horned animals, disease, stone, water, Brahmana,
> dog, nails, iron; those who die of hunger, poison, fire and cholera;
> those who are killed by a bull, a thief, a Candala, **a woman in her
> menses,** Sunaki, Sudra, washerman; those who commit suicide or die by
> fall from a tree, hill, wall or precipice; those who die in water, on
> cot, in firmament, in bondage.
>
> Those who are killed by Urdhvocchista, Ardhocchistha or Ubhayoccista;
> those who die of wounds by weapon on horseback.
>
> **All these deaths are known as bad deaths where no rite of
> Aurdhvadehika or pinda-dana is performed.** If the same is done by
> mistake it is all destroyed in the air.
>
> But desiring welfare of the deceased and out of fear of the people's
> reproach his sons or grandsons or sapindas should perform **Narayana
> Bali**, O bird. By that the relatives of the deceased are purified. This
> is stated by yama. There are no other means. When **Narayana Bali** is
> performed they become fit for aurdhvadehika.'

**Garuda Purana, Dharma Khanda, Chapter IV**